# Programa que solicite por teclado una cadena y después la muestre un carácter por renglón

Tags: java

Hola soy bastante nuevo en esto de la programación y estoy atorado con un programa que nos pidieron  desarrollar el cual es un programa que solicite por teclado una cadena y después la muestre un carácter por renglón. Enserio les agradecería mucho su ayuda

Comment: Hola, que has intentado?

Comment: Comienza por mostrar el código que has intentado para que podamos ayudarte; no sabemos como es tu código, ni en que parte estas atorado. Si quieres lee [ask] y has el [tour]

Comment: De momento tengo solo esto ya que de aqui no se como lograr que se muestre como se me solicita                                                                                                                         String cadena;
Scanner teclado = new Scanner (System.in);
System.out.print("introduce el texto ");
cadena = teclado.nextLine();  
System.out.println(" el texto es " + cadena);

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Answer (score 0):

El problema que tienes es que en tu texto no llegas ha hacer nada con la String, prueba con algo asi:

```
String cadena="hola";
    for (int i = 0; i < cadena.length(); i++){
        char letra = cadena.charAt(i);
    System.out.println(letra);
        }
```

Espero haberte ayudado.

Comment: Evita responder a preguntas en donde el OP no haya demostrado sus intentos por resolver el enunciado, o no haya especificado el problema. Lee [answer], sobre todo la sección _contesta preguntas **bien formadas**_.